# How to compute the higher $K$-theory of a triangulated category having a semi-orthogonal decomposition?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-k-theory, triangulated-categories

I am starting to learn the $K$-theory of triangulated categories and is stuck with the following.
Let $\mathcal{T}$ be a triangulated category having a semi-orthogonal decomposition $\langle \mathcal{A_1},\mathcal{A_2},…,\mathcal{A_n}\rangle$.
I saw in the paper of Orlov titled Smooth and Proper Noncommutative Schemes and Gluing of DG Categories mentioning an isomorphism $K_i(\mathcal{T})\cong K_i(\mathcal{A_1})\oplus K_i(\mathcal{A_2})\oplus…\oplus K_i(\mathcal{A_n})$ for all $i$.How do we prove this result?
Are there any detailed references for this result?
I am thinking of applying this result to the case where $\mathcal{T}$ is the bounded derived category of coherent sheaves on an algebraic variety.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume $\mathcal{T} = D^b(X)$ and $X$ is smooth. Then $K_0(X \times X)$ has an algebra structure (with the convolution product) and $K_\bullet(X)$ is a graded module over this algebra. So, the idea is to use a decomposition of $1 \in K_0(X \times X)$ (the class of the diagonal $\Delta_X$) into a sum of idempotents, then the action of these idempotents will give the required direct sum decomposition.

To construct the required decomposition of the diagonal, note that there are objects
$$
R_i \in D^b(X \times X)
$$
such that the corresponding Fourrier--Mukai functors are the projection functors for the semiorthogonal decomposition, see Theorem 7.1 in [Kuznetsov, Alexander. Base change for semiorthogonal decompositions. Compos. Math. 147 (2011), no. 3, 852--876]. Moreover,
$$
[\Delta_X] = \sum [R_i]
$$
and $[R_i] \in K_0(X \times X)$ are the required idempotents.

If $X$ is singular, the argument is essentially the same, but you need to replace $K_0(X \times X)$ by the subgroup of $G_0(X \times X)$ formed by classes that are perfect over each factor.

If $\mathcal{T}$ does not have a geometric origin, but is enhanced, say, by a DG-algebra $A$, the argument is still the same, but you need to replace $K_0(X \times X)$ by the Grothendieck group of appropriate category of $A$-bimodules.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help.

Answer (score 4):

This is also an immediate consequence of the Waldhauden additivity property of algebraic K-theory, which says (in one formulation) that any semi-orthogonal decomposition $T=\langle A,B\rangle$ gives rise to a direct sum decomposition of $K(T)$ (and hence $K_i(T)$). But it is easy to extend this to semi-orthogonal decompositions of length $n$ by induction. See for instance Lemma 2.8 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.12858.pdf for a reference.

Comment: Thank you very much for your information and help.